# Работа с Activity в facebook api

Tags: facebook-widgets, facebook-api, facebook, javascript

Каким образом можно записать действие пользователя в Activity на его стене?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook graph api and open graph - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/. То что вам нужно